# I have trouble crafting a dig spell in Ars Magica 2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I want to create as my first spell the following recipe: Shape is 'Touch' + dig and its stored in the 'Book and Quill' item. I used my blue points so level it up from the occulus. My crafting altar is build up correctly as my main blocks are cobblestone and cap pieces are redstone blocks. Every tutorial I read and watched starts with either of the following statements:

1) Throw a blank rune in the crafting altar.

OR

2) Put the recipe book on the lectern.

No matter what I do, I cannot put the 'Book and Quill' with the recipe on the lectern.
When I first throw on a blank rune, the crafting altar starts swirling with symbols and the lectern has a transparent red book shape on top of it, but I still cannot place it. I can place my 'Arcane Compendium' in but it does nothing. I tried connecting the crafting altar with an obelisk, powered up with vintium dust, by using the crystal wrench. It said that its connected, but had no effect.

I searched a lot around the net, but I could not find an answer to my problem.

So why my lectern book slot is red and I cannot place my 'Book and Quill' containing the recipe on it to continue the spell crafting process?

EDIT: Replacing the  crafting altar's cobblestone with witchwood did not help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to the problem.

After you pick up the book from the Inscription Table, you have to open it by placing it in your hand and right clicking. Then give it a name and click the 'sign' button. Then the book image looks like an enchanted book and can be placed on the lectern to craft the spell.

Answer (score 0):

If your Book and Quill item is still named "Book and Quill" and not whatever name you have given your spell, then you have not properly crafted a spell recipe. What you need to do is place it in the Inscription Table, select the runes you want, and then pull it out of the table.

If your spell recipe has been properly crafted, then you need to place the book on the lectern by right-clicking. If there is already a book on the lectern, you can remove it by sneak right-clicking (SHIFT + Right-click). After that, you follow the recipe as described in the book.

There is a chance that you (or someone else if you're in multiplayer) were in the process of making another spell. In this case, you need to clear the crafting altar. To do this, right-click on the crafting altar block (should be the top-most middle block in the structure). This will refund all the items used so far in spellcrafting, minus any Etherium and the initial blank rune.

Comment: I re-created the process and named the spell 'Dig', before I picked up the book from the inscription table. The title of the item is 'Dig', but it still appears as 'Book and Quill' image in my inventory and I am still unable to put it on the lectern.

Comment: I found a solution to the problem. After I pick up the book from the Inscription Table, I have to open it and manually sign it with a name. Then the book image looks like an enchanted book and can be placed on the lectern to craft the spell.

Comment: @Fotti If you found a solution to your own problem, you can post it as an answer. It's totally fine to answer your own question. This will help others in the future that have the same problem.